# Displaying ® symbol in Silverlight

Tags: xml, silverlight, xaml, unicode, encoding

Folks!

I am trying to display ® and superscript TM symbols in my silverlight app. I want to save the text containing the symbols in a resx file.

Things i have tried:

> - Copy paste the ® symbol from any document to resx file. ® symbol gets
>     displayed in the resx file. But, when
>     running the silverlight app,
>     xamlparseexception is thrown.
> - Use unicode text &#174 instead of ® symbol in the resx file. Same
>     xamlparseexception thrown.

My resx file encoding is utf-8.

Appreciate your thoughts!

EDITED:
Incorrectly mentioned @ instead of ®.

Redbox in the snapshot is how the symbol gets displayed in Silverlight. Bluebox is how it needs to be displayed.
[image]

EDIT 2 and SOLUTION:
The way the symbols are displayed are dependant on the font used. Also, displaying superscripts in Silverlight is a bit tricky. But, the simplest solution i found was to create the superscript text in Windows character map tool and copy paste it your app resource file.

Comment: Copy paste the ® symbol from this page to resx file worked for me using silverlight 3 in VS2008. Which version are you using and what code are you using to set the value form the resx file to the screen?

Comment: @John: I managed to display the symbol, but size the quite small that the ® symbol gets displayed as a circle with a dot inside it. I have attached a snapshot of how is looks in red box and how it should be in a blue box. thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the ® symbol varies with the font being used.  Some fonts draw it as a superscript others draw it as a standard character.  For example the "Lucida Sans Unicode" font treats it like a Superscript where as the "Lucida Grande" font draws it like a normal character.  Hence you need to be careful which font you use to render it.

I'm seeing a case in point just as I write this.  The text box where I'm writing this in SO has the ® character as a superscript whereas looking at the preview box below the character is normal size.