# Silverlight always places Trademark symbol at start

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am putting into the TextBlock some text with trademark (TM): `"Some text™"`

But text block shows (TM) sign at start - `"™Some text"`!

How can I show (TM) sign in the place where I put it in the string?

**P/S:** It looks unbelievable but it's true)

Comment: Only use FlowDirection = RightToLeft if you write Arabic or Hewbrew text in the box.

Comment: It is RightToLeft. Problem only with (TM) other small unicode symbols are showing fine.

Comment: @AlexanderMolodih Why are you using right-to-left on English text?

Comment: Try "[hello]world" for more fun.  It is just an inappropriate setting for English text.  Use TextAlignment instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. It looks like I really don't need it. Place your answer and I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Silverlight 5 :**

Following will work with Silverlight 5 with Typography Support..

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Some Text..!!"
     Typography.Variants="Normal" />
    <Run Text="TM"
         Typography.Variants="Superscript" />     
 </TextBlock>
```

Go to following link for more on Open Type Support in Silverlight 5..
http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/02/silverlight-5-and-wpf-4-opentype-support

**Silverlight 4 :**

No direct support for typography in Silverlight 4 but it can be achieved for few numbers and basic arithmetic. For which you can check following link on Silverlight Forums..

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/64169.aspx/1

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
<TextBlock Text="Some Text"/><TextBlock Text="™"/>
```

Comment: That's an ugly workaround. It's certainly better to fix the original problem, if that's possible.

Comment: It seems from another thread on Stackoverflow:

The size of the ® symbol varies with the font being used. Some fonts draw it as a superscript others draw it as a standard character. For example the "Lucida Sans Unicode" font treats it like a Superscript where as the "Lucida Grande" font draws it like a normal character. Hence you need to be careful which font you use to render it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813645/displaying-symbol-in-silverlight

Comment: Generally I am getting this string from server, and this symbol can be everywhere. I've simplified my issue for this question

Comment: then try using a different font. maybe that would help!